# Two Rdlc Reports loading same time. One Report displaying and the other only after refresh click

Tags: asp.net, object, reference, reportviewer, rdlc

When I am trying to Load two Rdlc report in two report viewer with same data 
(one is Report and other is its Chart, both are loading simultaneously), the first report displaying correctly and the second one showing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". When I click on Reportviewer Refresh, it will load correctly.

```
          // First Report
            var dsmems = ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.GetDataSourceNames();
            ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dsmems[0], dataList));
            ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dsmems[1], br));
            ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dsmems[2], ColList));
            ReportViewerRSFReports.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            ReportViewerRSFReports.LocalReport.Refresh();

          // Second - graph 
            ReportViewerGraph.Reset();
            this.ReportViewerGraph.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            this.ReportViewerGraph.LocalReport.ReportPath = grpPath;
            var dsGrp = ReportViewerGraph.LocalReport.GetDataSourceNames();
            ReportViewerGraph.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dsGrp[0], dataList));
            ReportViewerGraph.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dsGrp[1], br));
            ReportViewerGraph.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dsGrp[2], ColList));
            ReportViewerGraph.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            ReportViewerGraph.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Both ReportViewers have attribute `AsyncRendering="true"`.

So I changed `AsyncRendering="false"` to one reportviewer and working fine.